# Prisma config error on docker swarm deploy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to deploy a prisma service on my docker swarm, but received:

> error: "services.prisma.environment.2 must be a string"

With the following docker-compose, the service runs fine.

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.25
    environment:
      - PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
```

Comment: Can you post the full configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-` it is not a sequence

```
environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
```